# how would one route this using Asp.Net WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a Restful service in Which I have a list of items, which could be queried as such:

```
 GET Api/Items
```

Which lists all items. 
But of course I'd also need these items to be listed as 'most popular', or 'belonging to user x' or 'belonging to category Y'

When glancing at the stackoverflow 2.0 api to see how they solved this they named their URLS as following:

```
 GET Api/Items/MostPopular
```

And this methodology I'd like to adopt as well as it does seem to make sense and looks good.

However, How can I configure Web-API to allow this URL syntax as well?
The default route is as following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

So I would guess that I need to add my extra routing in front of it.
I could do it like this: (If this even works)

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "SpecializedApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/MostPopular",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

But then it would add the MostPopular bit for all my controllers which I don't like.

Does something like this work?

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "SpecializedApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/Items/MostPopular",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
 );
```

And is this really the way to go as my routing table would quickly become very big and possibly unmaintainable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be to add another get action and configure a generic `route` rather then a `specific` route.

First add action for most popular

```
// add action for Most Popular
[ActionName("MostPopular")]
public MyResult GetMostPopular()
{
     return null;
}
```

Setup route to handle the action.

```
// Controller with ID
// To handle routes like `/api/Items/1`
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndId",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: null,
    constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // Only integers 
);

// Controllers with Actions
// To handle routes like `/api/Items/MostPopular`
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ControllerAndAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
);
```

Comment: Interesting. But this would also enable the MostPopular method on controllers which don't have this? Like Api/Member/MostPopular right?

Comment: Yes, offcourse and you will also able to add other method as well without changing the routes like Api/Member/RecentPosts and Api/Member/FlagedPosts etc.

Comment: ah ok. So if I don't supply a MostPopular method on my Members controller, this wouldn't even be called? That sounds like a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best maintainable if you do not deviate from the default to much,
however you should specify the controller and action in the route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "SpecializedApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/Items/MostPopular/{id}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "wheretogo",
                    action = "wichactiontotake",
                    id = RouteParameter.Optional 
                  } 
);
```

or this works too:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
    name: "SpecializedApi", 
    routeTemplate: "api/test/{action}/{id}.html",
    defaults: new { controller = "test" } 
);
```

Check out this link when using fake files for configurating the IIS:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx